# Passing an array as function argument without defining a variable

Tags: arrays, c, parameter-passing, function-call

How can we pass an array directly to a function in C?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int arr[]) {};

int main(void) {
    int nums[] = {3, -11, 0, 122};
    function(nums);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of this, can we just write something like `function({3, -11, 0, 122});`?

Comment: One option is to wrap the array inside a struct: `struct foo { int arr[10]; }; struct foo wrapped = {{3, -11, 0, 122}}; fx(wrapped);`

Comment: @pmg but that still uses an intermediate variable

Comment: Ah! Didn't read the question title with enough attention; anyway leaving the comment here :-)

Comment: @pmg Not your fault sir, I expanded  the title based on my understanding of the question. the initial version had no mention of that. Apologies.

Comment: *"can we just write something like"* - What happened when you tried?

Comment: No worries @SouravGhosh, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals). Something like

```
function((int []){3, -11, 0, 122});
```

Comment: One of those things that work in C but not C++, I think.

Comment: @dxiv: it works in C99 and later, but not in C++ (yet?).

Answer (score 4):

You could pass array as compound literal as below.

```
function((int []){3, -11, 0, 122});
```